# Add suffix to ALL filenames in subfolders recursively via Batch

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to add a suffix to all filenames (not the folders) recursively in all subfolders.

*1.txt to 1_1.txt* and so on

I tried and started with this:

```
set "suffix=_1"
set "rootdir=C:\Test"
set "fileTyp=.txt"
set "filefilter=*.txt"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%rootdir%\%filefilter%" /B^|findstr /V /I /B "%suffix%"') do ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni%suffix%%fileTyp%"
```

but it only works for the specific filetype in an specific folder and when the batch file is in the same directory as the .txt files. Otherways the error `cannot find the file specified` shows.

Comment: This site is not a code request service, you have already included a [robocopy] tag, so you already have an idea of the command you have, or intend to, use for this task. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54651043/edit) to include the code you want us to help you fix, _by including it formatted appropriately using the **`{}`** button_, and including a full explanation of how it fails to work as written and intended; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I think you want, give this a go:

```
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "C:\Test" /s /b /a-d ^| findstr /v "_1\.[^.]*$"') do (
   ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni_1%%~xi"
)
```

This will simply search through all filesusing `/s` in `dir` command, then exclude directories `/a-d` and exclude files already with suffix `_1.*` then we strip the filename into bits and rename the file to include suffix. for more on the expansion on those, see `for /?`

Comment: Almost, but your FINDSTR regular expression is wrong - it will prevent `abc_1.xyz.txt` from being renamed. Easily corrected using `findstr /v "_1\.[^.]*$"`

Comment: Thanks @dbenham. I was hoping that it would not be the case, but you are right, any filename is possible. Will ammend. Thank you.

Comment: @dbenham updated :)